# Aws S3 link to update the .apk not properly updating in Android

Tags: android, amazon-s3

In my scenario, I have uploaded .apk into aws s3 bucket but whenever I am sharing the link to another member along with public permission, when another member downloading at the time they have already installed same application but old apk. Now the problem is after updating the old .apk by new .apk, we are getting improper activity into applications.

I am sure it is not related to app issue. How we can suspect exact issue.

Comment: Every time if you made changes you need the change version in the `gradle` file, Android ecosystem to except new apk have upgraded version.

Comment: @Rajesh: This the reason we are getting application after updating also, few things are not working properly? 

Scenario is app is already installed then I am giving again another one new app aws s3 link from that link if we download and update the app...after that we are facing app UI and functionality little but varying.

Comment: Better you can try to uninstall app and try to install ? Because some phone not properly reinstall if you do manual apk install

Comment: @Rajesh is there anything alternative options available to avoid this issue. Can I release the android app in play store for testers like a apple testeflight

Comment: Yes Please go with Play-store or TestFlight otherwise you will face these kind of issues.